# Slider com jQuery no WordPress não está rodando no IE

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Estou produzindo [meu site](http://rafaworks.com.br/), no Chrome está tudo ok como sempre, mas no IE o Slider não está rodando e não sei o que fazer.

Estou usando CSS3, [jQuery Easing v1.3](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) e jQuery 1.11.0.

Localizei o código que o Chrome usa pra rodar o slider,  mas não achei o problema ainda.

main.js:

```
homepage = function(){
    $("div.homepage div.content").append("<div id='next-slide'><i></i><div>");
    slide = 0;
    $("div.homepage  div.content").click(function(){
        slide++;

        if(slide == 1){
            $("#home-content1").animate({right:"-1500"},900, "easeOutCubic");
            $("#home-content2").animate({right:"-43"},1000, "easeOutCubic");
        }
        if(slide == 2){
            $("#home-content2").animate({right:"-1500"},900, "easeOutCubic");
            $("#home-content1").animate({right:"-43"},1000, "easeOutCubic");
            slide = 0;
        }

    }).hover(function(){
        clearTimeout(homepageSlide);
    },function(){
        homepageSlide = setTimeout("homepageSlideFunction()",5000);
    });

    homepageSlide = setTimeout("homepageSlideFunction()",5000);
}

$(document).ready(function() { 

});
```

CSS:

```
/*SLIDER PAG INICIAL*/
#home { overflow:visible; padding:0 ; float: right;}
#home .content { padding:0; height:423px; position:relative }
#home #home-text,
#home #home-text1 { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:350px; height:200px; cursor:pointer }
#home #home-text1 h1,
#home #home-text2 h4 { position:absolute; top:72px; left:0; width:350px; text-align:center; font:58px "ProximaNovaSemibold", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif bold; text-transform:uppercase; text-decoration:underline; line-height:54px; z-index:2 }
#home #home-text2 h4 { top:138px; left:23px; text-align:left; width:420px }
#home #home-text p { position:absolute; top:72px; left:25px; top:315px; margin:0; width:300px; font-size:26px; text-align:center; line-height:24px; z-index:2 }
#home #home-text2 p { top:345px; left:80px; width:280px }
#home #home-text1 .bg { position:absolute; top:10px; left:35px; width:280px; height:280px; -moz-border-radius:280px; border-radius:280px; background:rgba(0, 204, 255, 0.4); z-index:1 }
#home #home-text2 { position:absolute; top:0; left:-1500px; width:650px }
#home #home-text2 .bg { position:absolute; top:66px; left:44px; width:605px; height:252px; background:url(../img/content/home-texto2-bg.png); z-index:1 }
#home #home-content { position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0 }
#home #home-content1 { position:absolute; bottom: -30px; right:-30px }
#home #home-content2 { position:absolute; bottom:0; right:-1500px }
#home #home-content3 { position:absolute; bottom:0; right:-1500px }

#next-slide{ width: 56px; height: 56px; border-radius: 56px; -moz-border-radius: 56px; position:absolute; top: 315px; left: -80px; cursor:pointer; transition: background 0.5s;
-moz-transition: background 0.5s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition: background 0.5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition: background 0.5s; /* Opera */ font-size: 50px; text-align: center; line-height: 56px; border: 5px solid rgba(156, 90, 183, 0.3);}
#next-slide:hover{ background-color: #9C5AB7;}
#next-slide i{ top:12px; left:12px; width:42px; height:42px; border-radius:42px; -moz-border-radius:42px; background:#2c2c2c; transition: background 0.4s;
-moz-transition: background 0.4s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition: background 0.4s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition: background 0.4s; /* Opera */ }
#next-slide:hover i { background-position:-40px -406px }
#next-slide span{
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: -5px;
    color: rgba(156, 90, 183, 0.5);
    width: 66px;
    height: 66px;
    padding: 1px 0 0;
}
#next-slide span:hover{
    color: #fff;

}
/*SLIDER PAG INICIAL*/
```

Como eu filtrei e fui deixando só o essencial  ele deixou de ser automático também.

Comment: Tem como você adicionar esse Js nesse site WordPress ai http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/ e verificar se com isso vai funcionar ???

Comment: Olá. Colocar o link do site e pedir para as pessoas verem lá não é uma boa aqui. Depois que você resolver o problema (esperamos que resolva!), a pergunta perde o sentido e não será mais útil para ninguém. A melhor maneira de perguntar seria isolar o problema, tentar reproduzi-lo, e postar aqui mesmo o trecho relevante do código. Um bom ponto de partida é olhar o console nas ferramentas de desenvolvedor do IE, ele deve estar registrando algum erro. Sugiro editar a pergunta para incluir o erro e o trecho do código que o causou.

Comment: O que o @bfavaretto falou é 100% correto. O melhor a fazer é explicar *como* você construiu o slider, que bibliotecas usou, como está seu HTML, etc. Assim as pessoas que vão ter acesso mais fácil aos dados para te ajudar.

Comment: Eu editei, vê se da para entender. Vlw pela dica pessoal.

Answer (score 1):

O método padrão de disparar comandos jQuery no WordPress é encapsular tudo em:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { // $ poderá ser usado como atalho de jQuery
    // Nosso código
});
```

Então, no seu exemplo ficaria:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    homepage = function(){
        $("div.homepage div.content").append("<div id='next-slide'><i></i><div>");
        slide = 0;
        $("div.homepage  div.content").click(function(){
            slide++;

            if(slide == 1){
                $("#home-content1").animate({right:"-1500"},900, "easeOutCubic");
                $("#home-content2").animate({right:"-43"},1000, "easeOutCubic");
            }
            if(slide == 2){
                $("#home-content2").animate({right:"-1500"},900, "easeOutCubic");
                $("#home-content1").animate({right:"-43"},1000, "easeOutCubic");
                slide = 0;
            }
        }).hover(function(){
            clearTimeout(homepageSlide);
        },function(){
            homepageSlide = setTimeout("homepageSlideFunction()",5000);
        });

        homepageSlide = setTimeout("homepageSlideFunction()",5000);
    }
});
```

Olhando o código fonte de sua página, vejo que também tem o seguinte bloco que talvez possa ser inserido/adaptado dentro do `jQuery(document).ready()`:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
if(typeof(homepage) == "function"){
    homepage();
}
if(typeof(homepageRun) == "function"){
    homepageRun();
}
</script>
```